# Problem at building conf-pkg-config 2 when installing tsdl with opam on windows 64

Tags: ocaml, sdl, opam

I get this error when installing tsdl for my caml project:

```
#=== ERROR while compiling conf-pkg-config.2 ==================================#
# context     2.0.8 | win32/x86_64 | ocaml-variants.4.11.1+mingw64c | git+https:
//github.com/fdopen/opam-repository-mingw.git#opam2
# path        ~/.opam/4.11.1+mingw64c/.opam-switch/build/conf-pkg-config.2
# command     dash.exe -ec  pkg-config --help
# exit-code   127
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/conf-pkg-config-1212-9b8556.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/conf-pkg-config-1212-9b8556.out
### output ###
# dash: 1: pkg-config: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error message you have:

```
# dash: 1: pkg-config: not found
```

Have you tried

```
sudo apt install pkg-config
```